# Selenium vs. the NY Metropolitan Opera

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

First, obligatory advance apologies - almost newbie here, and this is my first question; please be kind...

I'm struggling to scrape javascript generated pages; in particular those of the Metropolitan Opera schedule. For any given month, I would like to create a calendar with just the name of the production, and the date and time of performance. I threw beautifulsoup and selenium at it, and I can get tons of info about the composer's love life, etc. - but not these 3 elements. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Link to a random month in their schedule](http://www.metopera.org/calendar#/on-stage?year=2018&month=10)

Comment: Can you post what have you tried so far?

Comment: Sure; variations on this (sorry about lack of proper formatting; still learning):

from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


link = 'http://www.metopera.org/calendar#/on-stage?year=2018&month=10'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)

driver.get(link)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

Comment: @JackFleeting What do you mean by "create a calendar"? What is the format you want the production, date/time stored in? Are you just printing it out? Save it to a file?

Comment: The end game is one Excel sheet with a "Season at a glance" calendar structure, with the whole season on one page. But for this I need those 3 elements, by day - along the lines of "for month in season, for day in month, a = date[day], b=title[day], c = start_time[day], with the three appended to a local list ("daily_performance") and each of these appended to the master ("mySchedule"). Once I have mySchedule I can easily manipulate it in Excel.
BTW, if there's a way to do the whole thing in pure python, please point me at the right direction...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that you should look for (in the future) on websites are calls to an API. I opened up Chrome Dev Tools (F12) and reloaded the page while in the Network tab.

I found two api calls, one for "productions" and one for "events". The "events" response has much more information. This code below makes a call to the "events" endpoint and then returns a subset of that data (specifically, title, date and time according to your description).

I wasn't sure what you wanted to do with that data so I just printed it out. Let me know if the code needs to be updated/modified and I will do my best to help!

I wrote this code using Python 3.6.4

```
from datetime import datetime

import requests

BASE_URL = 'http://www.metopera.org/api/v1/calendar'
EVENT = """\
Title: {title}
Date:  {date}
Time:  {time}
---------------\
"""


def get_events(*, month, year):
    params = {
        'month': month,
        'year': year
    }
    r = requests.get('{}/events'.format(BASE_URL), params=params)
    r.raise_for_status()
    return r.json()


def get_name_date_time(*, events):
    result = []
    for event in events:
        d = datetime.strptime(event['eventDateTime'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
        result.append({
            'title': event['title'],
            'date': d.strftime('%A, %B %d, %Y'),
            'time': d.strftime('%I:%M %p')
        })
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    events = get_events(month=11, year=2018)
    names_dates_times = get_name_date_time(events=events)

    for event in names_dates_times:
        print(EVENT.format(**event))
```

Console:

```
Title: Tosca
Date:  Friday, November 02, 2018
Time:  08:00 PM
---------------
Title: Carmen
Date:  Saturday, November 03, 2018
Time:  01:00 PM
---------------
Title: Marnie
Date:  Saturday, November 03, 2018
Time:  08:00 PM
---------------
Title: Tosca
Date:  Monday, November 05, 2018
Time:  08:00 PM
---------------
Title: Carmen
Date:  Tuesday, November 06, 2018
Time:  07:30 PM
---------------
Title: Marnie
Date:  Wednesday, November 07, 2018
Time:  07:30 PM
---------------
Title: Mefistofele
Date:  Thursday, November 08, 2018
Time:  07:30 PM
---------------
Title: Tosca
Date:  Friday, November 09, 2018
Time:  08:00 PM
---------------
Title: Marnie
Date:  Saturday, November 10, 2018
Time:  01:00 PM
---------------
Title: Carmen
Date:  Saturday, November 10, 2018
Time:  08:00 PM
---------------
Title: Mefistofele
Date:  Monday, November 12, 2018
Time:  07:30 PM
---------------
Title: Tosca
Date:  Tuesday, November 13, 2018
Time:  07:30 PM
---------------
Title: Les Pêcheurs de Perles  (The Pearl Fishers)
Date:  Wednesday, November 14, 2018
Time:  07:30 PM
---------------
Title: Carmen
Date:  Thursday, November 15, 2018
Time:  07:30 PM
---------------
Title: Mefistofele
Date:  Friday, November 16, 2018
Time:  07:30 PM
---------------
Title: Tosca
Date:  Saturday, November 17, 2018
Time:  01:00 PM
---------------
Title: Les Pêcheurs de Perles  (The Pearl Fishers)
Date:  Saturday, November 17, 2018
Time:  08:00 PM
---------------
Title: Mefistofele
Date:  Monday, November 19, 2018
Time:  07:30 PM
---------------
Title: Les Pêcheurs de Perles  (The Pearl Fishers)
Date:  Tuesday, November 20, 2018
Time:  08:00 PM
---------------
Title: Il Trittico
Date:  Friday, November 23, 2018
Time:  07:30 PM
---------------
Title: Les Pêcheurs de Perles  (The Pearl Fishers)
Date:  Saturday, November 24, 2018
Time:  01:00 PM
---------------
Title: Mefistofele
Date:  Saturday, November 24, 2018
Time:  08:00 PM
---------------
Title: Il Trittico
Date:  Monday, November 26, 2018
Time:  07:30 PM
---------------
Title: Mefistofele
Date:  Tuesday, November 27, 2018
Time:  07:30 PM
---------------
Title: Les Pêcheurs de Perles  (The Pearl Fishers)
Date:  Wednesday, November 28, 2018
Time:  07:30 PM
---------------
Title: La Bohème
Date:  Thursday, November 29, 2018
Time:  07:30 PM
---------------
Title: Il Trittico
Date:  Friday, November 30, 2018
Time:  07:30 PM
---------------
```

For reference, [here is a link to the full JSON response from the events endpoint.](https://bpaste.net/show/4c64fbb7616e) There is a bunch more potentially interesting information you may want but I just grabbed the subset of what you asked for in the description.

Comment: Thanks, DL; I'm probably not qualified to pass judgment, but in my opinion you are a genius! That's exactly what I was looking for.